# Loopback datasource.json - forcing SSL connection

Tags: loopbackjs

I don't see anything in the documentation about it. I need to be able to use an SSL connection to my Postgres db (accessing a Heroku instance externally). Is there a way to set this in datasources.json?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to set `"ssl": true` in the config for that datasource and have that propagated to the connector.